# Create data constructor for partially applied type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, constructor, algebraic-data-types, partial-application

Is it possible to create a data constructor for partially applied type in Haskell?

ghci session:

```
Prelude> data Vector a b = Vector {x::a, y::b}
Prelude> :t Vector
Vector :: a -> b -> Vector a b
Prelude> type T1 = Vector Int
Prelude> :t T1
<interactive>:1:1: Not in scope: data constructor `T1'
Prelude> let x = Vector
Prelude> let y = T1
<interactive>:46:9: Not in scope: data constructor `T1'
```

I want to create data constructor for type T1 - is it even possible? Or do I have to use newtypes, because it is not possible to manually define such function?

Comment: I think [this page](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:3GDV7F446NMJ:www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2013-May/108350.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) might be useful.

Comment: The type `T1` contains no values, so it's not possible to create a 'constructor' for it.

Comment: FYI, the "type of a type" is called a *kind*, which you can get by doing `:kind T1` in ghci.

Answer (score 6):

I'm a little confused as to what your goal is, but let's go through this bit by bit, and maybe I'll hit the right point:

`:t` tells you the type of a *variable*; it makes no sense when applied to a type, since it would just return exactly what you passed. Notice the errors here tell you that `:t` expects some kind of data value as a parameter:

```
Prelude> :t Maybe

<interactive>:1:1: Not in scope: data constructor `Maybe'
Prelude> :t (Maybe Integer)

<interactive>:1:2: Not in scope: data constructor `Maybe'

<interactive>:1:8: Not in scope: data constructor `Integer'
```

You **can** create a partial type:

```
Prelude> type T = Maybe
Prelude> Just 5 :: T Integer
Just 5

type T a = Maybe a -- alternately, with explicit type parameters
Prelude> Just 'a' :: T Char
Just 'a'
```

You **can't** create a *data constructor* for a partial type, since they don't represent data. What values could a `Maybe` or `Vector` have without being parameterized on a type? You might be inclined to think that `Maybe` could have the value `Nothing`, but `Nothing` is typed as:

```
Prelude> :t Nothing
Nothing :: Maybe a
```

The key being that `Nothing` can be *any* `Maybe a`, but it still needs an `a` to know it's `Nothing`. (It's sort of like if I told you "fetch me a glass of" instead of "fetch me a glass of anything" - you can't validly comply until I've at least finished my thought).

You can certainly create partially applied **functions** which will return a **complete** type *once they're applied*:

```
Prelude> let f = Just :: a -> T a
Prelude> f 5
Just 5
Prelude> :t f 'a'
f 'a' :: T Char
```

Answer (score 4):

GADTs can do this. GHCi session:

```
λ :set -XGADTs
λ :{
| data Vector a b where
|     Vector :: a -> b -> Vector a b
|     T1 :: Int -> b -> T1 b
| type T1 = Vector Int
| :}
λ :t T1
T1 :: Int -> b -> T1 b
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already a constructor for `T1`, and it is named `Vector`:

```
*Main> :t Vector :: Int -> b -> T1 b
Vector :: Int -> b -> T1 b :: Int -> b -> T1 b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Prelude> type T1 = Vector Int
```

This creates a **type** constructor for a `Vector Int`. Note that here `Vector` is used as a **type** constructor because you supply a type argument. You can query the **kind** of the type `T1` with `:k`:

```
Prelude> :k T1
T1 :: * -> *
```

This tells you that `T1` is a type constructor that takes a concrete type (`*`) and returns a concrete type.

To create a **data** constructor, you need to provide a **data** value for the first parameter of the `Vector` **data** constructor:

```
Prelude> let t1 = Vector 5
Prelude> :t t1
t1 :: b -> Vector Integer b
```

(Note that `Vector` is both a **type*** constructor as well as a **data** constructor because you used the same name on the left and right sides of the `data` declaration.)